# Manipulate browser history to view previous ajax content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a page (index.php) with this code:

```
<html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
      <div id="content"></div>  <!-- it contain the ajax response  -->
      <script>
        show_page('profilo',id); //call ajax and then show result
      </script>
      </body>
```

The "content" div contain the ajax response, and i have a lot of link on the response, when one of them is clicked another ajax function are executed..and the "content" value are updated with the new response.
What i want to do is to show the previous ajax content of the "content" div when the back browser button are clicked..i red many javascript solution to manipulate the browser history but i don't know how to call the previous function to show the first content. The problem are also that i don't have to show only the content with the argument of the code above, beacuse the argument may change during the navigation..there is a way to do that?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the generic history API, but you can try to accomplish this by using a frontend framework like `Backbone`.

Comment: @JayBlanchard was my error sorry, i haven't seen it on my profile! Now the problem is that this post are more detailed of the other one but i can't delete the other one because other questions are linked as duplicates of that one...what i have to do?